# Noetherian local domain of dimension one

Tags: commutative-algebra, noetherian, local-rings

While revising for my exam in Commutative algebra, I came across the following statement that:

> Let $A$ be a Noetherian local domain of dimension one. Let $x,y \in A$ with $x \neq 0$ and $y \in \mathfrak{m}$. Then $ax = y^n$ for some $a \in A$ and $n \geq 1$.

But I don't really understand why? Does this have anything to do with that in a Noetherian local domain every non-zero ideal can be written as a power of the maximal ideal? If yes, why do we even need an $a \in A$?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I don't get this question: do you have to show that for a given $x\ne0$ there are $a\in A$, $y\in\mathfrak m$ and $n\ge 1$ such that $ax=y^n$?

Comment: The exact wording would be the following way: Let $x,y \in A$ with $x \neq 0$ and $y \in \mathfrak{m}$. Then $ax = y^n$ for some $a \in A$ and $n \geq 1$. @user26857 
Edit: I have edited the question.

Comment: The condition can be reformulated as follows: $\bar y\in A/(x)$ is nilpotent. But $A/(x)$ is local Artinian, so...

Comment: I know that if $(A, \mathfrak{m})$ is local Artin, then $\mathfrak{m}$ is the only prime ideal and it is nilpotent, i.e. every element in the maximal ideal is nilpotent, so the whole $A/(x)$ is nilpotent, i.e. the maximal ideal. Is that correct?

Comment: @MBCLA yes，completely correct.

Answer (score 1):

If $A$ is a DVR, then every nonzero ideal in a DVR is a power of the maximal ideal $\mathfrak{m}$, and we have $x=ut^n$ for $t\in \mathfrak{m}$ being a uniformizer. However, if $A$ is not a DVR, then this is not true in general. Then 
$\mathfrak{m}$ is not principal.

Comment: Yes, I knew the one with unit $u$. But since here it is given that $a$ is in the ring, not necessarily a unit, I was confused. So, it is correct that in the case above $a$ would have to be in the unit? Is it also possible, that it is not a unit?

Comment: Yes, $a$ can be arbitrary. Then let $x'=ax\in A$ and write $x'=y^n$.

Comment: Ahhhhh, of course :D Such a stupid question from me! Thanks a lot for your reply :)

Comment: @DietrichBurde I don't think is true that every nonzero ideal is a power of the maximal ideal, unless you assume that $R$ is a DVR as it seems.

Comment: @user26857 You are right, it is not given, that $A$ has to be a DVR. I assumed it automatically without looking at it closer. But how can one see this statement otherwise, if the property with power of maximal ideal is not given?

Comment: Ah, sorry, I had assumed DVR.